# Wordpress Pagination not appearing

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am attempting to insert basic pagination on two pages of my wordpress blog but the pagination is not appearing at the bottom of the page. I am not sure what Im doing wrong as Ive seen a number of other examples of the exact same code I am trying to implement working just fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Code Being Used In Both Pages

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'content-projects', get_post_format() );
endwhile;?> 
<nav>
<ul class="pager">
<li><?php next_posts_link( 'Previous' ); ?></li>
<li><?php previous_posts_link( 'Next' ); ?></li>
</ul>
</nav>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: How many are your posts and posts per page? There need pagination?

Comment: The Content on these pages is going to continuously increase for the whole life of my blog so pagination is neccesary

Comment: I mean in this time, whether number of posts is enough (to create pagination) or nor

Answer (score 0):

Following code works perfect for me. May be this will work for you also. Please apply this code as it is.

```
<div class="nav">
<div class="alignleft numbers"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
```

And one more way to add pagination is to use a plugin.[Click here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/)

By this way you just need to add shortcode like :--

```
<div class="nav">
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Place this code where you apply your code of pagination.

Means instead of

<nav>
<ul class="pager">
<li><?php next_posts_link( 'Previous' ); ?></li>
<li><?php previous_posts_link( 'Next' ); ?></li>
</ul>
</nav>

Use the code that I suggested.